# ScrollView is not working when try to add as a subview

Tags: objective-c, scrollview, addsubview

I have problems with my scrollView! I have a view called Rootview and I wanna add three subviews to a scrollview. When I add the scrollview as a subview the middle view and the three subviews disappear. This is my code.. The Rootview (whole window) and the scrollview are outlets.

```
UIView *middleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 218, 2024, 218)];
[middleView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor yellowColor]];
[RootView addSubview:middleView];

//create new views for sap systems beginning from left

UIView *firstSystem1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 218)];
[firstSystem1 setBackgroundColor: [UIColor grayColor]];
[middleView addSubview:firstSystem1];

UIView *secondSystem1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(305, 0, 300, 218)];
[secondSystem1 setBackgroundColor: [UIColor grayColor]];
[middleView addSubview:secondSystem1];

UIView *thirdSystem1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(610, 0, 300, 218)];
[thirdSystem1 setBackgroundColor: [UIColor grayColor]];
[middleView addSubview:thirdSystem1];




CGSize scrollViewContentSize1 = CGSizeMake(2024, 218);

 [middleScrollView setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize1];
[middleScrollView addSubview:middleView];
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't adding your `middleScrollView` anywhere

change this

```
[RootView addSubview:middleView];
```

for this

```
[RootView addSubview:middleScrollView];
```

Comment: Sorry, I first forgott the last line. I need three subviews. It all works bud when I try to add the scrollview as a subview my middleView and the three small views on it disappear.

Comment: I found the mistaked. I changed the first line to                     UIView *middleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2024, 218)]; Now it works..